# Vector field and a solution of an ODE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-topology

I have this:

[image]

And my questions are :

1)what is :"The local theory of differential equations in a Banach space"

2)Why it's implies that each solution of (6) is equal to $\eta$

Please

Thank you .